# Flutter Navigate to Screen After User Clicks Link in Email Confirmation

Tags: flutter, api, async-await, navigator

I am attempting to Navigate to a screen based on an API response. When a user register's I have an API that sends a confirmation email with a link the user must click to verify their account / email. I am wanting to have my flutter app navigate to the user Dashboard screen after the user has clicked the link in the email to verify their account which will return status code 200.

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this in flutter.

Here is my code:

```
class EmailVerification extends StatefulWidget {
  const EmailVerification({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EmailVerification> createState() => _EmailVerificationState();
}

class _EmailVerificationState extends State<EmailVerification> {
  Future verifyEmail() async {
    var response = await userEmailVerification(Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).user.userID);
    await emailVerified(response);
  }

  Future emailVerified(dynamic response) async {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, kRegistrationTOC);
        });
    }
      print('Test');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    verifyEmail();
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UserData>(
        builder: (context, user, child) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              return false;
            },
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: eBackgroundColor,
              body: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                        child: Image(
                          height: 100.0,
                          image: AssetImage(
                              'images/some_image.png'
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      WidgetSpacer(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'An email has been sent to: ${user.user.email}. Click the link to verify your email address.',
                        style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 1.0
                        ),
                      ),
                      WidgetSpacer(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Didn\'t receive an email?',
                            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, kUserRegistrationID);
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Send again',
                              style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                color: Color(0xFF4A8082),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 15.0, left: 50.0, right: 50.0, bottom: 5.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 35.0,
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                            },
                            shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
                            ),
                            elevation: 10.0,
                            color: const Color(0xFFF7B666),
                            child: Text(
                              'Submit',
                              style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                  fontSize: 25.0
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that's where deep links come into play. You can use firebase dynamic links or any other of your choice. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening web url content in Flutter app using Firebase Dynamic Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578308/opening-web-url-content-in-flutter-app-using-firebase-dynamic-links)

Comment: I don't think that deep linking will solve my issue. I don't necessarily need to display the URL content within the app, What I need to happen is when a user receives an email to confirm their email address, the user may navigate from the app to their email to click the link, or use a totally different device such as pc laptop, etc. to click the link. I need the app to navigate the user to a new screen once the link is clicked. Essentially and in theory it needs a way to wait on the response.

Comment: in that case, you can implement your own socket connection to your server to get a value on user email verification or keep running a simple HTTP request, may be every 30 seconds or high, to your server checking if the user has verified or not.

Comment: Setting up a recurring HTTP request to check if the user has verified or not is what I was thinking. In theory this should run without the user having to click anything. Would this be best ran using the initState() function?